# Android: Background tiles not covering whole area

Tags: android

I was trying to apply that cross lines in background for that I have applied this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tiles"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp50"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp2"
    android:alpha=".8"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp2"
    android:alpha=".8"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
    android:text="Policies"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the output is

[image]

I have also tried 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
&
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

but that doesnt helped..

can someone please tell what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess this layout is used with a `Fragment` inside a `ViewPager`, right?  Is the `ViewPager` set to fill its parent?